# Add hidden field inside last td of tr of a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table which display list of regions with edit delete link. I want to add a hidden field at the end last td of tr of this table

```
 <table class="source-table dialog" data-control="regionEditList">
      <tr class="source-header">
          <th>Region name</th>
          <th style="width: 104px">Action</th>
       </tr>
          <c:forEach var="region" items="${regions}">
            <tr>
              <td class="regionName">${region.regionName}</td>
              <td class="region-edit-btns" data-control="region-edit-del">
              <a href="#" data-control="regionEdit">Edit</a>
              <a href="#" data-control="delRegion">Delete</a>
              </td>
        </tr>
         </c:forEach>
   </table>
```

Using jquery I can get list as tr

```
    var addWrapper = jQuery('[data-control=regionAddField]'),
    addField = jQuery('input[type=text]', addWrapper),
    addReset = jQuery('input[type=reset]', addWrapper),
    addBtn = jQuery('button', addWrapper),
    list = jQuery('[data-control=regionEditList]');
```

so I am appending a tr at end using

```
    list.append('<tr><td class="regionName">' + addField.val() + '</td><td class="region-edit-btns" data-control="region-edit-del">'+
                '<a href="#" data-control="regionEdit">Edit</a><a href="#" data-control="delRegion">Delete</a></td></tr>');
```

Now after getting regionId from Db I want to append a hidden field inside last td of above list.

Please let me know if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <table class="source-table dialog" data-control="regionEditList">
      <tr class="source-header">
          <th>Region name</th>
          <th style="width: 104px">Action</th>
       </tr>
          <c:forEach var="region" items="${regions}">
            <tr id="yourTr">
              <td class="regionName">${region.regionName}</td>
              <td class="region-edit-btns" data-control="region-edit-del">
              <a href="#" data-control="regionEdit">Edit</a>
              <a href="#" data-control="delRegion">Delete</a>
              </td>
        </tr>
         </c:forEach>
   </table>
var addpendElem = '<input type="hidden" id="someId"';
$('#yourTr :last-child').after(addpendElem);
```

Comment: Hi Deepu , Thanks for your answer. I don't have Tr Id I am adding TR at runtime using list.append(<tr><td><td></tr>). Now I want to append hidden field inside last td. Here loop is to show the list first time when data is loaded from DB